# Want a quicker solution using RECURSION

Tags: python, recursion, coding-efficiency

Question: Some people like to spam Internet chatrooms with the single word “LOL”. This often annoys some of the other users, who
will respond by announcing “One more LOL and I’m out”. Still other users will parody this response by posting “One more
‘One more LOL and I’m out’ and I’m out”, and so on, nesting more and more layers of “One more {X} and I’m out”.
Complete the recursive lol() function, which takes a positive (non-zero) integer argument representing the level of nesting

(“One more LOL and I’m out” represents one level of nesting). The function returns a string containing the appropriately-
nested version of the string above. For example, lol(3) would return the string (One more One more One more LOL and I’m out and I’m out and I’m out).

My solution :

```
def lol(y):
middle = "LOL"
part1 = " One more "
part2 = " and I'm out"
templist = []
answer = ""
if y == 0:
    print ("LOL")
else:
    for i in range(y):
        middle = middle + part2
    for j in range(len(middle)):
        templist.append(middle[j])
    templist.reverse()
    for k in range (y):
        templist.append(part1)
    templist.reverse()
    for h in range(len(templist)):
        answer = answer + templist[h]
print (answer)
```

I want to see one solution using recursion. Then I am curious to see the most efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you define "efficient"?

Comment: @ggorlen Good question. I should replace "I am curious to see the most efficient solution" with "I am curious to see easier solution with shorten lines of code than mine".

Comment: Sounds good, but if your code is working this is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: @ggorlen I did not know about that site. I will post my further code review questions there. Thank you!

Comment: @Prune I would like to note, there is a tag "coding efficiency". It seemed reasonable to ask such a question because of that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def f(levels_left):
    if levels_left==0:
        return 'LOL'
    return 'One More ' + f(levels_left-1) + ' And I\'m Out'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Great! If this answers your question, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not a recursive one, but still it doesn't require any lists:

```
def lol(y):
    return 'One more ' * y + 'LOL' + ' and I \'m out' * y

print (lol(3))
```

Output:

```
One more One more One more LOL and I 'm out and I 'm out and I 'm out
```

Comment: Not at all what OP wanted, but an ingenious solution! You don't even need the `if` statement for it to still work perfectly!

Comment: @RobBricheno thank you, but I should probably delete it, since it's out of the scope of OP's question.

Comment: Perhaps, but at least one person out there liked it :-)

Comment: This is literally the best solution, if you don't have a requirement like `must use recursion`.